# AWS API Gateway With no Authentication

Tags: aws-api-gateway

How can i create a API in APIGateway with no Authentication but Accept the request only from specific IP CIDR.

We have a requirement for client side SSL authentication for our API. But i see that API Gateway does not support the same. So we are using Cloudfare load balancer to do us the  client side ssl authentication and pass the request to API Gateway.

In the above case does cloud fare load balancer needs IAM credentials for SIGV4 request ? How can i provide permission to cloudfare loadbalancer to invoke my API ? As cloudfare has already authenticated my client i dont want cloudfare to authenticate with API Gateway.

Comment: Authenticating by CIDR is not sufficient, because unless I am missing something, with that configurarion, any CloudFlare customer could then just configure CloudFlare to access your API.

Comment: You can whitelist ips with a resource policy, but as mentioned in the above comment, it's really not sufficient in the scenario you are describing.